# List book title with specific genre from a text file with Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to output all book titles with the genre. This is the code so far:

```
query = input("Books from which genre are you looking for? ")
file = open("books.txt","r")
counter2 = 1
n = 0
lines = file.readlines()
for line in file:
  if query in line:
    counter2 += 1
    n += 2
print(counter2 , " - " , lines[n])
file.close()
```

However, it only outputs one title. I want it to output all the books in that genre.

This is the text file (books.txt):

```
Book one
Horror
300
Book two
Fantasy
150
Book three
Mystery
400
Book four
Romance
100
Book five
Fantasy
600
Book six
Fantasy
90
Book seven
Horror
150
```

Comment: I hope you covered `dictionaries` already. It will be really handy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typo in your code, the fix if you want to use the same code would be:

```
query = input("Books from which genre are you looking for? ")
file = open("books.txt","r")
counter2 = 0
n = 0
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
  if query in line:
    counter2 += 1
    print(counter2 , " - " , lines[n-1])
  n += 1
file.close()
```

and there can be many optimizations done like only iterating the lines which contain the genre. Also if you have the data handy you can convert book.txt to a dictionary like,

```
{
  "Horror": [
    {
      "name": "Book one",
      "cost": "300"
    },
    {
      "name": "Book seven",
      "cost": "150"
    }
  ],
  "Mystery": [
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "Fantasy": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

You would be accessing the data very fast with `file[query]`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using regular expressions? Every book entry consists of the title, genre and pages. Make an expression that capture those and matches the genre query.

```py
import re
query = "Horror" #input("Books from which genre are you looking for? ")
with open("books.txt","r") as fh:
    regex = re.compile(f"(?P<title>.+?)\n{query}\n(?P<num>\d*)")
    data = fh.read()
    results = re.findall(regex, data)
    for result in results:
        title, num = result
        print(title)
```

Or add all the books to a dictionary and filter afterwards:

```py
import re
query = "Horror" #input("Books from which genre are you looking for? ")
books = []
with open("books.txt","r") as fh:
    regex = re.compile(f"(?P<title>.+?)\n(?P<genre>.+?)\n(?P<num>\d*)")
    data = fh.read()
    results = re.findall(regex, data)
    for result in results:
        title, genre, num = result
        books.append({
            'title': title,
            'pages': num,
            'genre': genre
        })
result = [book['title'] for book in books if book['genre'] == query]
print(result)
# ['Book one', 'Book seven']
```